# PowerShell Regex for searching in two lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying for regular expression for matching the following line in powershell

```
Add :
Some text here
```

Only two lines here it need to search,

But as of now I got the following regular expression which is searching the whole paragraph. I am stuck here please anyone help me

```
Add :+[\u000A]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Code snippet for the regex is as follows:

```
 $RegEx = "Add :+[\u000A]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*" 
    $requestforregex = "Requested for : [a-zA-Z0-9 \(\)\-]*" 
   $matchedItems = [regex]::matches($ticket[1].Body.Text.replace('&amp;','&'), $RegEx,[system.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline)
   $requestefor =( [regex]::matches($ticket[1].Body,$requestforregex,[system.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline))[0].Value.Replace("Requested for : ","")
```

Comment: Can you provide some details like the code used with the regex?

Comment: Check if your input data isn't already line-separated. If yes, you'll need a non-separated data, such as `[IO.file]::ReadAllText("filename")`.

Comment: The data is coming in the form of a single string. @Vesper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
$RegEx = "Add\s*:[\r\n]+.*"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Add%5Cs*%3A%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B.*&i=Add%20%3A%0D%0ASome%20text%20here). Here, the `[\r\n]+` will match 1 or more CR or LF symbols and `.*` will match any 0+ chars other than  a newline. Note you cannot use `Singleline` option you used in your code.

To match the text at the start of a line, add `(?m)^`:

```
$RegEx = "(?m)^Add\s*:[\r\n]+.*"
```

where `(?m)` is the inline version of the `RegexOptions.Multiline`  modifier option.